# A question about spam prevention recognized by SE network as spam

Tags: support, spam-detection

I am trying to post the following question on [Web Applications SE](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/) but I keep getting the error "*this looks like spam*".
Therefore, I tried to create a [Web Applications SE Meta](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/) question about this but got the notification that I need to have 5 reputation points to post on the meta there → currently I have just 1 reputation point there.

I might need to notify that I use this network since 2012 and my question is definitely not spam.

## Screenshot 1:

> [image]

## Screenshot 2:

> [image]

## My question

**How to solve this problem?**

---

## The question I am trying to post:

> ## How to know an email service is reliable?
>
> I use Gmail and I contemplate moving to another email service provider because of some Gmail policies I don't like, such as:
>
> - The automatic addition of interacted email addresses to "contacts"
> - Not being able to totally block email addresses by a badlist ("blacklist") without them going to a SPAM folder and without the need to set a filter to automatically delete SPAM folder emails if they do go there
> - Non minimal approach by containing "starred" or "all mail" and even "social" and "chat".
> - I had a case where I created a label (which I grasped as Directory) and when I deleted all mail it was deleted although I was sure it won't get deleted; I was sure this would be an exception even to "all mail" label ("folder")
> - Automatic synchronization (or easily mistaking to synchronize) `Android-operated` smartphone contacts with Gmail or Google contacts
>
> ### Before using Gmail
>
> I actually used an email service that was wonderful for me about seven years ago → [mail.com](https://mail.com) (which with the company running it or anyone of their behalf I am not associated in any way besides using their service in the past) but I stopped using *mail.com* and moved to Gmail because:
>
> When I used their *mail.com*, a bot of the university I took some courses at at the time, recognized emails I sent from *mail.com* as spam and all went to SPAM folder of the recipients and the university website programmers wanted to not do anything about that and their replies were rude and deterministic so I though it would be nice to avoid similar situations by using Gmail.
>
> ### After using Gmail
>
> About seven years passed since I finished my studies in the aforementioned institute and many changes happened in my mind and my life and I adopted a minimalist approach in regards to web applications and by that reduced the amount of applications I used in about 75% and I don't recognize why any similar problem should occur in the future and eager to leave Gmail and perhaps create a new account at *mail.com*
>
> ### My problems
>
> - I don't know what was changed with *mail.com* and if they are still the same
> - I don't know how to choose an email client that will be generally reliable or shall I be irreverent and say "totally reliable" in the sense that it won't be grasped by receiving email servers as spammy such as in the case described above
>
> ### My question
>
> How to know an email service is reliable?

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of the error you're getting when you try to post it?

Comment: My bet is on that link to `mail.com` as that site I end-up on looks dodgy.

Comment: @rene I tried to remove the link --- it didn't help, sadly

Comment: On another note: Are you sure that question is on topic? While carefully worded it still feels like *Web application recommendation requests* and those are off-topic per their help center.

Comment: Remove the mail.com posted as plain text either.

Comment: @rene I had no intention to ask there for a recommendation; my only intention is to ask there how to know of an email client would generally be considered spammy or not --- what standards should it have?

Comment: You mention the exact same domain 6 times, of which one is a hyperlink. I get why that would trigger a spam filter. Probably removing all but one mention of said domain would make you able to post the question.

Comment: I think this needs a dev that runs that content through the spam regex.

Comment: Even then, the question would be pretty much too broad. There are a million and one reasons a mail service could be considered spammy, and it all depends on the recipient.

Comment: Very long questions are known to trigger it, and the existing dupes here are for that case, but your question doesn't seem very long, so none of those apply.

Comment: I'm pretty sure question length isn't that significant a trigger, if at all, @SonictheAnonymousHedgehog. Keywords are much more important.

Answer (score 1):

I guess the issue has been resolved now. It doesn't mark it as spam. I tried posting this question and reviewing it and it didn't showed any remark of spam either.

[image]

Just to check if the question can get posted, I edited one of my deleted questions [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1698114/how-to-get-my-product-key-back)(you won't be access this question if you don't have 10k on SuperUser.com so posting an image [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OrToP.png) too) to this and it worked